# Where is the Update Event step in Dynamics CRM 365 process workflow editor?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

## Goal:

> Show **total sum** of `Activity` entities related to `Project` entity in a form field named `Total Activities` in Dynamics CRM 365

Following [these guys](https://www.magenium.com/Techblog/2014/February/Aggregates.aspx), for our `Project` entity's form edtior, we've created a normal Whole Number field named `Total Activities`.

As suggested in the blog, we've Created a workflow process to run on `Activity entry` entity:

[image: workflow process]

with a name `Activity counter`:

[image: activated as a process]

which will be activated as a process when

- Record is created
- Record status changes
- Record is deleted

[image: Options for Automatic Processes]

We've reached to **Step Properties**:

[image: Step Properties]

The blog says the following:

> In the Update Event step, increment the attendee count by 1, and the Total Revenue (Event) field by the Fee field from the Registration record.

We're not able to see that Event step thing anywhere in the process editor.
How to get to the following screen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use rollup fields](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn832162.aspx)

> In Microsoft Dynamics 365, rollup fields are designed to help users obtain insights into data by monitoring key business metrics. A rollup field contains an aggregate value computed over the records related to a specified record, such as open opportunities of an account. Also, you’ll be able to aggregate data from the activities directly related to a record, such as emails and appointments, and activities indirectly related to a record via the Activity Party entity. In more complex scenarios, you can aggregate data over the hierarchy of records. As an administrator or customizer, you can define rollup fields by using the customization tools in the Dynamics 365 Web application, without needing a developer to write code.

Answer (score 0):

The steps you are following are for **Real-Time Workflows**. You should UNCHECK the "**Run this workflow in the background (recommended)**" checkbox in order to see the the Update Event Steps. The items in the red square box are the Update Event Steps

[image: The items in the red square box are the Update Event Steps]